# toString causing an error inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, arrow-functions

I have this implementation:

```
const DataManager = (container) => {
  if (document.getElementById(container)) {
    const generateRandomEmail = () => {
      let myNum = 25;
      return myNum.toString();
    };
  }
};

module.exports = DataManager;
```

I am using webpack with babel to build my code, everything works just fine if I remove toString(), but once I add it I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of
> object '#'

Any idea why might this be happening?

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3",
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 5 versions",
            "ie >= 8"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/data-manager.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'data-manager.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: "DataManager"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].min.css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].min.css"
    })
  ],
  devtool: "inline-source-map"
};
```

P.S. not only `toString()` is causing an error, this is also causing the same error also: `console.log([...Array(5)]);` or `toFixed()`

Comment: Usually this error occurs when you mix `import` and `module.exports`
Here it raised in GitHub https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039

Comment: That's right, but unfortunately it is not the case here, if I remove toString() everything works just fine, I tried to delete the dist folder, node_modules and runnig `npm i` again, same error

Comment: @AliIssa console.log it before returning check if result is the same

Comment: @ShawnVn same error

Comment: @AliIssa well, that's kinda weird :)) console.log the `typeof` myNum. or `parseInt(myNum).toString()`

Comment: same same, that's weird indeed!

Comment: really weird. I also would think, that it is mix of `module.exports` and `import`.

I also spotted something different. When you call the function `DataManager`, you get the DOM Element and then you define another function `const generateRandomEmail`.
You cannot call that function and it is never executed.
I think you should return that function `return generateRandomEmail`